# Managing proper timing between read and write switching in pyserial?

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial, rs485

I am using pyserial module in Python 3. I am first writing to the serial and then changing the baudrate from 300 to 4800 and then reading it. But there is some issue in between. So how can i make sure that every byte of the message has been sent (on the physical line) before changing the UART settings?
Below is my code.

```
try:
    ser.write(Acknowledgement_message) #Sending Ack Message to Serial
    print("Acknowledgement messsage sent")  
except:
    print("could not send Acknowledgement message")
    ser.close()
    return ""
ser.baudrate=new_baudrate   #Setting new baud-rate as 4800 after sending the Ack message
time.sleep(tr)
print("baud-rate set to 4800")
datablock = ""
try:
    x=ser.read() #Again reading the data block
    print(x)
except:
    print("Could not read STX----")
    ser.close()
    return ""
```

Is there any solution to manage the proper timing (changing the baud rate when the stop bit of the last byte has left the UART)?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific reason you use two different Baud rates for writing and reading? Also, have you tried closing and re-opening the port with the new Baud rate after you send the message? 

The serial port should keep using the Baud rate it was opened with until it is re-opened with a different Baud rate.

Comment: Yeah, it is specified in the IEC62056 standard that i have to change the baudrate.. i tried that one too but didnt worked..

Comment: It is odd for the same device to use different Baud rates to read and and write. You can use `flush()` (the [latest](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.flush) pySerial libraray) to wait until all the output data is written.

Comment: i have to cross compile this as i am using yocto os :(